# Not allowing to specify a user in comment

Tags: discussion

i tried to add the queries in the comment ,but i couldn't able to tag the username.Even i tried adding it with **"@"** Why its so.? Is there any reputation limit needed for it.?
[image: Have specified as user,but its not diaplaying]

Comment: Quoting the linked FAQ: *Tab name completion can be used, and that knows when @name is unnecessary and will then not automatically complete names. It also does not work for editors.*